# Underwater terrain modeling

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, interpolation, saga

My task is to model the surface of a lake bed, calculate volume of it and visualize it as 3D a surface.

I have acquired depth measurements in a small lake using echosounder. The precision should be pretty high (<5 cm for depths and 3-5 cm for RTK GPS position). Points are placed regularly with 2.5 m intervals between them.
I also have digitized shoreline from high resolution orthomosaic.

Which would be the best interpolation algorithm for such tasks? (QGIS, GRASS, SAGA, maybe some other free software does such things?). The biggest challenge has been to find an algorithm, in which I can define the shoreline as 0 value which has to be taken in account.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at mb-system, which is specically made for mapping sea floors (I have no experience, I just know it exists):
http://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/mb-system_overview.html

Anyway, you could consider converting you shoreline line to points before interpolating.

Comment: It seems that MB System is more for multi-beam and side-scan sonars. What i have is just a point cloud with depth values.

Comment: If it is a point cloud then it perhaps reminds DEM from LiDAR http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/pt_PT/docs/training_manual/forestry/basic_lidar.html

Comment: Some folks in our lab developed the ToPCAT algorithm for working with point clouds [link](http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/gridsphere/gridsphere?cid=tools). It is also available for use in ArcMap 10.1 with the GCD tool bar [link](http://gcd.joewheaton.org/downloads). I have never used this I just know it exists and was developed specifically for use with bathymetry data.